# Breakpoint do not hitting during debugging

Tags: android

Why could breakpoint in NetBeans (Android 1.5) not fire?

Comment: Android recommends you to use Eclipse for its app development. Android offers you ADT plug-in for eclipse. If you are new to Android development it is always wise to go with Eclipse since you have lot of documentation and support for the same.

Comment: In theory, any debugger that supports JDWP for remote debugging will work.  In practice, most Android developers use Eclipse, and you're more likely to get a useful answer.  (My first question is usually, "does a check mark appear on top of the breakpoint bullet after the debugger connects?", but I don't know what the equivalent would be in NetBeans.)

Answer (score 1):

You have a guide called [Developing In Other IDEs](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/other-ide.html) which tells you how to debug outside eclipse.

Take a look at [Attaching a Debugger to Your Application](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/other-ide.html#AttachingADebugger).

Answer (score 0):

if you have a braodcast reciever in your application the breakpoint will not hit. i dont know why but this happens to me whenever i have a broadcast reciever in my application. the breakpoint works fine in all other cases.
I use eclipse BTW.