# breakpoint in activity associated with statusbar notification is ignored

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, breakpoints

i am new to android development but have used eclipse extensively.
i'm running some android application in the eclipse debugger in the emulator. i have no problem stepping through the code and control stops at my breakpoints. except... my application creates a status bar notification. when i open the the notifications and click on my notification (in the emulator) it starts the activity associated with that notification.
i have some breakpoints set in the methods of the activity but the debugger seems to ignore them. i can from the log that the code executed - the debugger just ignores the breakpoints and doesn't stop on them.

is there something i need to do (perhaps in the manifest or in eclipse) to enable
stepping through activities such as this (that are started by android when the user clicks to open a status bar notification)?

Comment: Did you try to debug using a real device (not an emulator)?

Answer (score 0):

Breakpoints do not hit in broadcast receivers. I haven't found yet documentation on this, but the following threads suggest that this is common knowledge:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3617722
2. [Breakpoint not triggers in Broadcast Receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6294665)

If anyone knows otherwise, please correct.