# Breakpoint not triggers in Broadcast Receiver

Tags: java, android

The title of the question pretty much sums it all, I want to debug my code in Broadcast Receiver but the break-point doesn't triggers, I am executing my android application from **Debus As --> Android Application**. Please help!

[edit]

Here is my Broadcast Receiver code:

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context cxt, Intent intent) {

    try {

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        String taskName = bundle.getString("TaskName");
        String taskRingTone = bundle.getString("TaskRingTone");
        long endDateInMillis = bundle.getLong("EndDateInMillis");

        //to disable alarm if enddate reached.
        checkEndDate(cxt, (AlarmManager)cxt.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE), endDateInMillis, pendingIntentId);

        Intent reminder = new Intent(cxt, Reminder.class);

        reminder.putExtra("TaskName", taskName);
        reminder.putExtra("TaskRingTone", taskRingTone);

        reminder.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        cxt.startActivity(reminder);


    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

}

and here is code i am using to register my receiver in the manifest:

```
        <receiver android:process=":remote" android:name="Alarm"></receiver>
```

Comment: Can you post some code and Manifest? That'll help make sure your stuff is setup right

Comment: @Spidy: I've posted the code.

Comment: You cannot startActivity on a BroadcastReceiver. Pepi has the right solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why do you run your receiver in a separate process?

You have to put some intent filters that define what type of messages this receiver will get:

For example:

```
<receiver android:name=".Alarm">
<intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
</intent-filter></receiver>
```

This receiver will fire when SMS message is received.